# callback url wont work in twitter

Tags: twitter, callback, twitter-oauth

i m login via twitter and then it said redirecting you to the application , this may take few moments in a popup page then it redirect to a blank page with that url

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/rafgallery/callback.php?type=twitter&oauth_token=***************&oauth_verifier=************
```

what can be wrong please ,?
in the twitter app setting i have callback url like that

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/rafgallery/callback.php?type=twitter
```

whats wrong please ? is the url wrong or what ?

Comment: It must be something involving the URL. Could you paste the format of my_url_callback but censor the sensitive parts?

Comment: @SantaClaus thanks for your answer , but i have just edited my question, because now it redirect to a blank page . because i made this callback url above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get it to work with that link

```
    http://www.mywebsite.com/rafgallery/callback.php?type=twitter
```

in really i created new API keys and it worked, i dont know what was wrong with the first API KEYS.

Answer (score 0):

The oauth_callback parameter is sent as part of the call for a request token to the request token endpoint: (https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token).

The call to the authenticate endpoint is then made with just the request token you receive back.

Have you tried removing the oauth_callback parameter from the authenticate url?

See the [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i have just edited my question, because now it redirect to a blank page . because i made this callback url above